# Trying to setup argumentless git push - how to configure origin as default upstream?

Tags: git

I have a development branch that I branch off of for specific features. I'd like to be able to create/checkout a branch, do some commits, and just issue:

```
git push
```

or

```
git push origin
```

to push to the remote repo. Either command is fine with me if possible, I just want to not have to specify my branch every time I push. I've tried setting up some config with:

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

but when I try to do either of the above commands to push, I just get the error:

> ```
> fatal: The current branch myBranch has no upstream branch. 
> To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use:
>
> git push --set-upstream origin myBranch
> ```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create new branches locally (using `git branch` or `git checkout -b`) those branches are just local branches and do not contain any tracking information. So when you push, they will not automatically push and as such create a remote branch, unless you explicitely tell them to do that.

One way to do that is already mentioned in the error message: `git push --set-upstream origin remoteBranchName` or `git push -u origin remoteBranchName` for short. After that, the `upstream` configuration for `push.default` (as well as the `simple` configuration becoming default in Git 2.0) will make `git push` push that branch.

You could also try setting `push.default` to `current` as that will always push the current branch to the remote branch with the same name. But I actually never tried that, and I would advise against it, as it removes the symmetry between push and pull that `upstream` (or `simple`) achieved.

Btw. if the remote branch already exists, but you don’t have a local branch, just checking out that remote branch (`git checkout remoteBranchName`) will automatically create a new local branch and set up the tracking information.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, without specifying it for every new branch, there's no real way to default-push to the origin? Am I reading your response correctly?

Comment: I don’t think so, no. At least not without setting `push.default` to `current`; you could set that locally for your one project though (just run `git config push.default current` without the `--global`).

Comment: Ok, I don't think current will work unless I'm just misunderstanding how that works. My new branch has to be named the same as the upstream repo?

Comment: If your local branch is named `foo` then it will push to origin’s branch `foo`. If it is named `bar` it will push to `bar`; no exceptions. That’s why upstream/simple are better; they are explicit but flexible.